# HTML Video Player with Navigation Link Button

Tags: html, html5-video, embed, video.js

Can someone tell me how I can change a video by clicking on E01-E02-E03 etc.?

The video in the player only plays from here: `<source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />`

When I click E01-E02-E03 it opens directly to the link.
When I click on an episode, I want it to play directly from the player.
Is it simple to do it?
Best regards

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <video id="videoPlayer" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="593" height="364" poster="" data-setup="{}">
      <b>Season 1</b>
      <a href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">E01</a>
      <a href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">E02</a>
      <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

  <script>
    const player = videojs('videoPlayer', {});
  </script>
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried embedding the video link to the text only and couldn't make it play through the video player

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924894. You need the click event to set the new source of your player, rather than linking to the URL.

Comment: Thank you was helpful but how can i make the Episode embed links to switch via the player, <a href="#">E01</a> it switches from link and i can't place the src: link too to see if switch property

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but the `<script>` tag for video.js should be above the script tag that uses `videojs()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be calling `player.src()` to load a new source. Something like:

```js
// You'll want to be more specific than `a` of course
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    player.src(a.href);
  });
});
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/wesaficeba/edit?html,output

Comment: More specific .. like? I try it and episode doesn't change but at least isn't opening at the src and that's something!

Comment: You're not going to actually all `<a>`s to be new videos, so you'll want a more specific selector as in the jbin example.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much that's seems to work excellent! Is it easy on switch episode click to start play the videos auto?